# Create event in UTC - room doesn't respond in user's TZ

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

Another issue I'm facing in my Outlook Calendar integration...

From my external platform, I create events on the Outlook Calendar using the Microsoft Graph API, and I pass the datetimes in UTC.

The event is created on the user's calendar in the correct time slot, but the room's response has a strange behaviour: on the web version of Outlook the time that is read on the room's response email is converted to the current user's timezone, but on the desktop version of Outlook the time is shown in UTC.

This is a problem because it can confuse users. Does anyone know why this happens, and if so, what's the solution?

Comment: are you sending the prefer timezone header with your requests? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/findmeetingtimes-example

Comment: Actually I am not, I am just sending the times in UTC like this: `"start": {  "dateTime": "2019-05-05T10:00:00",  "timeZone": "UTC"}`. Would that solve my issue?

Comment: In my experience Exchange (behind the Graph) "understands" things better when you work on the user's timezone and sending the prefer timezone header, I suggest you give it a try.